# Tweetsharp HTTP 403

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter, twitterizer

I have a problem logging on to Twitter using ASP.NET 4 C# and Twitterizer. First I create the TwitterService object

```
TwitterService Service = new TwitterService(key , secret);
```

Then Request the Token:

```
OAuthRequestToken requestToken = Service.GetRequestToken(
                    "http://127.0.0.1:16608/CallbackHandlers/TwitterCallback.ashx");
```

Then get the uri:

```
Uri uri = Service.GetAuthorizationUri(requestToken);
```

And redirect:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(uri.ToString());
```

My app is redirected to Twitter. When I enter my user ID and password I get a HTTP 403 error. If I press the back button on the browser Twitter is no longer asking me to enter the USERID and PWD but instead there is just and Authorize button. When I press the Authorize button, Twitter redirects back to my site and everything proceeds as expected.

I cannot seem to successfully enter the USERID and PWD without getting a 403 error. When I get the error the browser address is showing:-

*https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize*

Please note that the Callback URL is my twitter app setup is the same as the one in the  GetRequestToken call above.

It appears as if Twitter does not know where to go next!!!.

Any assistance would be greatly welcomed.

Robert.